# What's wrong with this mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone spot what is wrong with this URL rewrite? I can't get it to pass anything to GET (the script loads, but no parameters are passed):

```
RewriteRule ^archive(/(.*))?$ archive.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want to map "archive/browse/" to "archive.php?action=browse".

Comment: Why did you accept Chacha’s answer? I thought you can’t get anything passed to `$_GET`?

Comment: Because it solves most cases that require my desired outcome (though not mine specifically). By accepting it, other users with a similar goal will more easily find the most likely solution.

It's the best answer currently, but I will be happy to switch and accept a different one it if a more effective solution is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^archive/(.*)$  archive.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Would rewrite anything after `/archive/` to `archive.php?action=test/dir/path`

Answer (score 3):

You can get some conflicts when [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) is enabled. If it’s enabled, Apache first tries to find a file with a similar name to map the request to before passing it down to mod_rewrite. So a request of `/archive/browse/` ends in `/archive.php/browse/` before mod_rewrite can map it to your `/archive.php?action=browse`.

Try to disable it with:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Although if nothing is passed, your scenario makes more sense

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: The option doesn’t change anything concerning mod_rewrite. It just stops Apache from looking for similar named files. Another solution would be to rename the file, if MultiViews is really the cause of this behavior.

Comment: I know, I was asking about (/(.*)), is the inner group still $1?

Comment: @Vinko Vrsalovic: No, that’s `$2`. But he said nothing gets passed, so I don’t think it’s the rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]*) archive.php?action=$1 [QSA,L]
```